# How to ignore @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod from testng results?

Tags: java, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

Following is a *sample* test case created using `testng` framework,

```
public class MyTest {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
    }

}
```

I am getting following `testng-results.xml` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" total="2" passed="2">
  <reporter-output>
  </reporter-output>
  <suite name="Surefire suite" duration-ms="15" started-at="2018-01-22T11:17:46Z" finished-at="2018-01-22T11:17:46Z">
    <groups>
    </groups>
    <test name="Surefire test" duration-ms="15" started-at="2018-01-22T11:17:46Z" finished-at="2018-01-22T11:17:46Z">
      <class name="com.my.test.MyTest">
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="beforeMethod()[pri:0, instance:com.my.test.MyTest@3567135c]" name="beforeMethod" is-config="true" duration-ms="4" started-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z" finished-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- beforeMethod -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="test1()[pri:0, instance:com.my.test.MyTest@3567135c]" name="test1" duration-ms="0" started-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z" finished-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- test1 -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="afterMethod()[pri:0, instance:com.my.test.MyTest@3567135c]" name="afterMethod" is-config="true" duration-ms="1" started-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z" finished-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- afterMethod -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="test2()[pri:0, instance:com.my.test.MyTest@3567135c]" name="test2" duration-ms="0" started-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z" finished-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- test2 -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="beforeMethod()[pri:0, instance:com.my.test.MyTest@3567135c]" name="beforeMethod" is-config="true" duration-ms="0" started-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z" finished-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- beforeMethod -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="afterMethod()[pri:0, instance:com.my.test.MyTest@3567135c]" name="afterMethod" is-config="true" duration-ms="0" started-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z" finished-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- afterMethod -->
      </class> <!--com.my.test.MyTest -->
    </test> <!-- Surefire test -->
  </suite> <!-- Surefire suite -->
</testng-results>
```

Notice that `afterMethod` and `beforeMethod` are also considered as test-methods. I want o ignore these methods from testng-result.xml as I am using this XML for further processing.

I have following questions,

- Is there anyway to avoid `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod` methods in test result xml file?
- Is there anyway to differentiate between before and after methods from test-method XML tag? 
  (*i.e.* I can strictly name my methods to `beforeMethod_Ignore()` and `afterMethod_Ignore()` but it will be kind of hack instead of solution)

I've gone through following links but couldn't find anything yet,

- http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-testng-xml
- http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/include-exclude-test-methods-in-testng
- [Exclude Test in testNg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42242416/exclude-test-in-testng) etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no direct way of excluding configuration methods from the `testng-results.xml` file.

But all said and done, the current entries in the `testng-results.xml` still lets you distinguish a configuration method from a test method.

For a configuration method there's an extra attribute named `is-config="true"`.

See below for excerpts from your own xml file

```
<test-method 
    status="PASS" 
    signature="beforeMethod()[pri:0, instance:com.my.test.MyTest@3567135c]" 
    name="beforeMethod" 
    is-config="true" 
    duration-ms="4" 
    started-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z" 
    finished-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z">
    <reporter-output>
    </reporter-output>
</test-method> <!-- beforeMethod -->
```

But for a regular `@Test` method, the attribute `is-config=true` would not be available.

See below :

```xml
<test-method 
    status="PASS" 
    signature="test1()[pri:0, instance:com.my.test.MyTest@3567135c]" 
    name="test1" 
    duration-ms="0" 
    started-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z" 
    finished-at="2018-01-22T16:47:46Z">
    <reporter-output>
    </reporter-output>
</test-method> <!-- test1 -->
```

Would that not help you with your downstream xml processing ?

If that still doesn't work for you, then the other alternatives would include:

- you would build your own version of `org.testng.IReporter` implementation wherein you construct this xml and then wire it in as a listener.
- You create a package called `org.testng.reporters` wherein you duplicate the contents of the class `org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter` into this package, alter the method `org.testng.reporters.XMLSuiteResultWriter#getTestResultAttributes` to add extra attributes to the method if its not a `@Test` method.